# realmio - realm objects can only be accessed from thread they were created

Tags: android, thread-safety, realm

Question sound similar to previously asked questions. I have referred those but couldn't find solution to this problem I'm having.

```
private AddCartItemDialog.CartItemListener cartItemListener = new AddCartItemDialog.CartItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOkClick(Product cartItem, int quantity) {

            realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {

                    DraftInvoice draftInvoice = bgRealm.where(DraftInvoice.class).equalTo("shop.id", shopId).findFirst();


                    InvoiceItem invoiceItem = bgRealm.createObject(InvoiceItem.class);
                    invoiceItem.setPrice(cartItem.getPrice());
                    invoiceItem.setId(cartItem.getId());
                    invoiceItem.setQuantity(quantity);
                    invoiceItem.calculateTotal();

                    draftInvoice.getInvoiceItems().add(invoiceItem);

                    updateCartItemCount(draftInvoice.getInvoiceItems().size());
                }
            }, () -> {

            }, error -> {
                error.printStackTrace();
                Logger.e(error.getMessage());
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelClick() {

        }
    };
```

Error log shows following error -

```
08-28 15:10:25.214 4996-4996/com.example.realshoptest W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
08-28 15:10:25.214 4996-4996/com.example.realshoptest W/System.err:     at io.realm.BaseRealm.checkIfValid(BaseRealm.java:449)
08-28 15:10:25.214 4996-4996/com.example.realshoptest W/System.err:     at io.realm.ProductRealmProxy.realmGet$price(ProductRealmProxy.java:159)
08-28 15:10:25.214 4996-4996/com.example.realshoptest W/System.err:     at com.example.realshoptest.models.Product.getPrice(Product.java:75)
08-28 15:10:25.214 4996-4996/com.example.realshoptest W/System.err:     at com.example.realshoptest.NewInvoiceActivity$1$1.execute(NewInvoiceActivity.java:76)
08-28 15:10:25.214 4996-4996/com.example.realshoptest W/System.err:     at io.realm.Realm$1.run(Realm.java:1187)
08-28 15:10:25.214 4996-4996/com.example.realshoptest W/System.err:     at io.realm.internal.async.BgPriorityRunnable.run(BgPriorityRunnable.java:34)
08-28 15:10:25.214 4996-4996/com.example.realshoptest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
08-28 15:10:25.214 4996-4996/com.example.realshoptest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-28 15:10:25.214 4996-4996/com.example.realshoptest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-28 15:10:25.214 4996-4996/com.example.realshoptest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-28 15:10:25.214 4996-4996/com.example.realshoptest W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-28 15:10:25.214 4996-4996/com.example.realshoptest E/TestShopApp: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
```

Error occurs at this line - `invoiceItem.setPrice(cartItem.getPrice());`

This piece of code seems to work from my understanding but it does not as I'm accessing objects async'ly in same thread. What am I missing here ?

Comment: You're accessing cartItem

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes thank you for pointing out. How can I pass `cartItem` to dialog, update its quantity and get it back in listener ?

Comment: Pass the id instead and query for the object inside the execute block

Answer (score 3):

```
public void onOkClick(Product cartItem, int quantity) {
```

This line receives a `Product` from the UI thread's Realm Instance

```
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
```

This call creates a Realm instance for the background thread

```
                invoiceItem.setPrice(cartItem.getPrice());
```

`cartItem` still belongs to the UI thread's Realm instance, therefore it cannot be accessed on the background thread

Two solutions:

1.) send the parameters only to the background thread

```
    public void onOkClick(Product cartItem, int quantity) {
        final long cartItemId = cartItem.getId();
        final String price = cartItem.getPrice();
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
                DraftInvoice draftInvoice = bgRealm.where(DraftInvoice.class).equalTo("shop.id", shopId).findFirst();
                InvoiceItem invoiceItem = bgRealm.createObject(InvoiceItem.class);
                invoiceItem.setPrice(price);
                invoiceItem.setId(cartItemId);
```

or

2.) requery the object with the background thread's Realm instance

```
    public void onOkClick(Product cartItem, int quantity) {
        final long cartItemId = cartItem.getId();
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
                Product product = bgRealm.where(Product.class).equalTo("id", cartItemId).findFirst();
                DraftInvoice draftInvoice = bgRealm.where(DraftInvoice.class).equalTo("shop.id", shopId).findFirst();
                InvoiceItem invoiceItem = bgRealm.createObject(InvoiceItem.class);
                invoiceItem.setPrice(product.getPrice());
                invoiceItem.setId(cartItemId);
```

The second solution is cleaner.

Comment: no matter what I do I still see Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created. - nightmare..

Comment: @68060 No, that just means you are doing unnecessary steps. If you don't erratically switch between threads, you won't run into this exception.